# Regex for including escaped HTML tags with other Regex

Tags: regex

I have this substring:

```
&lt;a href="http://www.somesite.com/" target="_blank"&gt;
```

And have dug up on the internet this Regex to identify the URL portion of this string.

\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]

However, this Regex isn't inclusive of the enclosing escaped HTML text **`&lt;a href="`** and **`" target="_blank"&gt;`**.

I need to be able to identify the full string in a large document, and so that includes composing additional Regex for the unescaped HTML parts of the above string. What would the Regex look like in order to find the above string?

Thanks!

Comment: [You shouldn't try to parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

Regex's probably not a good idea with html. But, since you have a strange case of character references used as markup, it probably isin't really html.

This Perl sample might work, but I'm not really sure:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $samp = '
 &lt;a href="http://www.somesite.com/" target="_blank"&gt;
 <a target="_blank" href="http://www.someothersite.com/" &gt;
';

my $regex = qr{
(
 (?:<|&lt;)a
    (?=\s) (?:(?!&gt;|>)[\S\s])*
    (?<=\s) href \s* = \s* 
        " \s* ((?:https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]) \s* "
    (?:(?!&gt;|>)[\S\s])* (?<!/)
 (?:>|&gt;)
)
}x;


while ($samp =~ /$regex/g) {
    print "In: '$1'\nfound: '$2'\n--------\n";
}
```

Output:

```
In: '&lt;a href="http://www.somesite.com/" target="_blank"&gt;'
found: 'http://www.somesite.com/'
--------
In: '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.someothersite.com/" &gt;'
found: 'http://www.someothersite.com/'
--------
```