# Regex statement not including full string

Tags: regex

I am using this regex:

```
\b(((\S+)?)(@|mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://)\S+)\b
```

to match this string of text (yes, it includes escaped HTML):

```
&lt; ahref="http://www.somesite.com/" target="_blank"&gt;
```

But when I run it in Expresso (or any other regex program), all I retrieve is:

```
ahref="http://www.somesite.com
```

I need the whole string, including `&lt;` and `target="_blank"&gt;`

What am I missing in my Regex to make this work?

Comment: Don't use regexes to parse HTML code.

Comment: Your question is incomplete and a candidate for closure. As it stands .* is correct, but I am 100% sure you don't want this.

Comment: If you want to use regex to parse html (which *is* possible), read this before you do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284176/doubt-in-parsing-data-in-perl-where-am-i-going-wrong/4286326#4286326

Comment: @Lucasus I am not worried about this being HTML. In .NET this is just a string, and I need the Regex to identify this exact string from  a document so I can remove it from a file that I am consuming. But this Regex isn't pulling up the entire string. How do I add in the &lt; and "_blank"&gt;? Thats all I am asking.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127532/regex-for-including-escaped-html-tags-with-other-regex/8130040#8130040 from yesterday. It had an answer in it, did you check that?

Comment: @sln The solution assumed I was using perl. I am only asking for a solution that involves pure Regex. I will handle what I am doing with it in the language of my choice. My question is restructured in this post to be as deliberate as possible: What Regex do I need to include &lt; and target="_blank"&gt; in the Regex I have been using. And FYI, the regex in this post is different than the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What am I missing in my Regex to make this work?"
`&lt;[\s\S]*?\b(((\S+)?)(@|mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://)\S+)\b[\s\S]*?&gt;`

Comment: thanks. I came up with a temporary solution but this looks better. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading your regex, you're looking for something between two word breaks (i.e. white space, or start/end of line, etc); then, anything other than whitespace, followed by anything that looks like a URI up until the next word break, so your pattern is explicitly looking for something that does not contain the spaces that you say you're after.

Comment: I see \S is causing that. What is an alternative character for S to include a discreet space then?

Comment: `\s` is any whitespace; `\S` is anything other than whitespace - fell free to add the extra group(s) as required.

Comment: Consequently, adding \s in place of \S fails to match anything. Can you explain what you mean by add more groups?